# undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I am new To Heroku ,first time i try to install Heroku toolbelt and after that run the command heroku login i am getting this error

```
  heroku login
! Heroku client internal error.
! Search for help at: https://help.heroku.com
! Or report a bug at: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/new

Error:       undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
Command:     heroku -version
Version:     heroku-toolbelt/3.42.50 (i686-linux) ruby/2.0.0
Error ID:    77319efb12804249b20ed45248dd6194


More information in /home/giri/.heroku/error.log
```

and *error log file contains 
*

```
Heroku client internal error.
undefined method []' for nil:NilClass /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/jsplugin.rb:60:incommands'
/usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/jsplugin.rb:228:in find_command' /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/jsplugin.rb:13:intry_takeover'
/usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/cli.rb:28:in start' /usr/local/heroku/bin/heroku:25:in
```

Comment: try this `heroku update`

Comment: i am getting same error again  Error:undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    Command:     heroku update

Comment: `gem uninstall heroku` this what is return

Comment: i try to reinstall several time still i am getting same error

Comment: which ruby version are you using?

Comment: ruby 2.0.0 and rails 4

Comment: do you have latest heroku toolbelt?

Comment: yes latest one only i installed but still it getting error

Comment: it give you error on heroku login or every heroku command

Comment: every heroku command i am getting same error